# grails 2.0 - running in Jetty, running in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, jetty

I'm currently deploying to a VPS where I'm using Tomcat 7 and I'm seeing lots of complaints deploying the most Barebones grails app, e.g.:

```
  SEVERE: The web application [/BareBones-0.1] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-1]  but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
  Feb 8, 2012 4:32:53 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
  SEVERE: The web application [/BareBones-0.1] appears to have started a thread named [H2 Log Writer PRODDB] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
  Feb 8, 2012 4:32:53 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
  SEVERE: The web application [/BareBones-0.1] appears to have started a thread named [H2 Log Writer PRODDB] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

Additionally, I often run out of memory just re-deploying a WAR file, even though I have 1GB dedicated and 2 GB Burst.   E.g. when I run the Tomcat stop command, I get:

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

on the stop.

So, I'm wondering if anyone can give me a pointer as to whether I might see less problems with Jetty in their experience.  My final web app won't be a very large / heavy traffic site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [known Tomcat issue](http://www.google.ru/search?q=tomcat%20permgen), happens very-very often (actually I never saw any app without such problem). It means that there is something wrong with your app, or (more common) with a library that your app is using. There is a list of 'well-known mistakes' - http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/OutOfMemory

Btw, sometimes it's much easier to restart Tomcat on deploy, instead of using hot-deploy.

Comment: I guess I'm surprised to have these kinds of errors with the most bare bones (Grails) app.  Do you know how Jetty compares to Tomcat?

Comment: Yes, even simple app can have such problem (and as for me - it's Tomcat's fault). I've used Jetty only for development, and can recommend it there, and never used Jetty in production, but I heard few times that it's working well.

Comment: ... so why do people go with Tomcat?  Because it's "older, more established"?

Comment: Heh, good question! :) Yes, I think because it's old, well known, mentioned in every book, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks, good reference.  Certainly look like folks gave a lot of up votes because they agree with the answer (rather than its quality in regard to detailed info).